# Excel 2013 VBA Workbooks.Open opens with wrong filename

Tags: vba, excel

When I attempt to open a certain target .xls file using the Workbooks.Open command in an Excel VBA macro, the target Excel file opens with a "1" appended to the end of the file name.  This altered filename shows up in the file window ().  With each subsequent attempt (manually closing the target Excel file & re-running the script) the appended number at the end of the target filename increments by one.

The target Excel file itself does not appear to be corrupted, as I am able to open the file manually in windows explorer without any issue.  Also, when I do open it this way, the filename shows up correctly (without the '1' appended to the end).  Looking at the 'Type' column in the Explorer window, it shows that the target file is 'Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet', so the file extension does match with the actual file format.

Below is the code that I am using:

```
Public Sub Import_TD_TVs()

     Dim ActiveWB As Workbook
     Dim srcTDWB As Workbook

     Dim wkbkStr As String


          Set ActiveWB = ActiveWorkbook

          wkbkStr = "X:\sites\DTS_Data_Files.xls"

          Set srcTDWB = Workbooks.Open(wkbkStr, , False)

End Sub
```

Any assistance on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: open task manager and make sure no other instances of Excel are open.  Then clean out your temp directory.

Comment: So, the filename, when opened, becomes "DTS_Data_Files.xls (1)" or "DTS_Data_Files1.xls"? (Or some other way?)  Sounds like it's a second instance of that workbook.  What happens if you restart your computer, and run the code first thing?

Comment: FYI - `Looking at the 'Type' column in the Explorer window, it shows that the target file is 'Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet'` - Explorer shows the "Type" based solely on the file extension, not on what the file actually is.  To see that, create a text file with a .txt extension, then use Explorer to rename it to have a .xls extension.  It will then display it as a "Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet".

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if the target workbook was originally saved as a template (.xlt) file and then the extension manually changed (to .xls) in Windows Explorer. You can open the target workbook and do a 'save as...' to .xls file format.

Comment: Thank you!  That was exactly the issue.  I found that when I opened & performed a 'Save As', .xlt was listed as the default file type in the 'Save As Type'. As soon as I saved it as an .xls file, closed it & re-ran the script, this time it opened it with the correct filename.  Kudos!!